# Keep the format of a text box in excel and insert it in an email body

Tags: excel, vba, email, textbox

I tried to create a vba codes to help me send emails to different clients.

I put all email body in a text box in excel with specific formatting. The issue I have now is when the email body inserted into an email the body format got lost.

Question : How can I keep the format of the text box?

```
Sub test_email_template()
    Dim name, email, body, subject, copy, place, business As String
    
    
    name = Range("B4").Value
    email = Range("C4").Value
    body = Format(ActiveSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Text)
    subject = " Payment Summary Reports"
    copy = Range("D2").Value
   
'replace name'
body = Replace(body, "Email Title", name)


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
    
         .to = email
         .cc = copy
         .subject = subject
         .body = body
         
         .display
        
    End With
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
End Sub
```

Below is the text box format I want to keep

[image]

Comment: `I put all email body in a text box in excel with specific formatting.` What specific formatting?

Answer (score 0):

you would need to use [.htmlbody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody). The idea is to write your message in excel cell with html, for example:

```
<p><font font face="Arial">Dear Email Title</p>
<p><font font face="Arial">Attached please find your up to date Payment Summary Reports.</p>
<p><font font face="Arial">Kind regards</p>
<p><font font face="Arial">John Johns</p>
```

Just put this in excel cell as your copy/paste body and then do the replace and put this text in .htmlbody = body

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to copy the text with formatting. Of course you'd need to make changes to this code to accommodate your requirements.

but `xlSheet.Range("C1:C2").copy` is the important code to copy cell text to clipboard with the Rich Text format.

You can have the

- salutation (Deal Email Title) in cell `C1` as a formula so that it can be updated using formula.
- rest of the body with Rich Text formatting in Cell `C2`

Reference: [Copying clipboard content into outlook mail item using VBA](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/paste-clipboard-to-outlook-with-vba/a1a27b25-1534-42ac-ae82-281e66ba30b6)

```vb
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    xlSheet.Range("C1:C2").copy

    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .BodyFormat = 3
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .subject = "Your Subject here"
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.collapse 1
        oRng.Paste
        .Display
    End With
   
 
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set olInsp = Nothing
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Set oRng = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    'MsgBox "Email(s) Sent!"
```