# How to copy text from a textbox in excel to paste it into an email. VBA

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, textbox

I'm trying to improve the macro for sending files to clients.
Everything was fine until the boss decided that the email text should be left in the correct format. Previously, the macro took the text from a cell. I am now trying to change this so that the email text retains the format. Highlights, hyperlinks etc.

I have changed the original macro several times according to what I found on the internet but I keep getting an error. Unfortunately I am just starting with VBA and I am already lost here.
I would be very grateful for your help.
[Keep the format of a text box in excel and insert it in an email body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69580309/keep-the-format-of-a-text-box-in-excel-and-insert-it-in-an-email-body)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYeq2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvM3m.png)

```
Sub Mail()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object

Set wb = Workbooks("BankDetails.xlsm")
Set ws = wb.Sheets("MessageBody")
Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Data")
Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Batch")
Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MessageBody")
    xlSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Copy


    Dim i As Long
    Dim i2 As Long 'For the number of passes (?)
    
    
        lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lastRow
                    
            klient = ws2.Cells(i, "A")
            
           zalacznik1 = ws.Cells(4, "B") & ws.Cells(5, "B")
          zalacznik2 = ws.Cells(4, "B") & ws.Cells(6, "B")
         zalacznik3 = ws.Cells(4, "B") & ws.Cells(7, "B")
            
        Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
        'Create Item  Outlook Element
        
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        With OutMail
            
            'Sender e-mail address
                        
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = ws.Cells(1, "B")
                       
            'E-mail address of the recipient, can also be several with ; separate
            
            '.To = ws2.Cells(i, "B")
            .BodyFormat = 3
            .BCC = ws2.Cells(i, "B")
            'from column C
            
            .Subject = ws2.Cells(i, "C")
            
            'The text to send in column D
            'Maximum 1024 characters
            'The text is accepted without formatting
            
            '.body = body
                                   
            'Add attachements w. reference to column B in sheets1 / MessageBody
            
            .Attachments.Add (zalacznik1)
            .Attachments.Add (zalacznik2)
            .Attachments.Add (zalacznik3)
            
            Set olInsp = .GetInspector
            Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
            Set oRng = wdDoc.TextBoxes
            oRng.collapse 1
            oRng.Paste
            
            'Here the mail is displayed
            .Display
            
            'Here the e-mail is immediately placed in the outbox
            '.Send
            
        End With
        
        'Empty object variables
        Set OutApp = Nothing 'CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set OutMail = Nothing  'OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        Set olInsp = Nothing
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        Set oRng = Nothing
        'Turn on pause
        'Outlook can't process the orders quickly enough, hence the pause
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        
       ' ws2.Cells(i, "D") = "Done"
        ws2.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Done, " & Now()
         
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please clarify this 'the email text should be left in the correct format'.

Comment: Yes, I pasted email text into textbox as is it in the email.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `WordEditor` you have access to a big part of MS Words Object model, including it's `Range` object, so you can use its `PasteSpecial` method.

In the below code I also made a few other minor changes such as taking the `Outlook.Application` object out of the loop (why would you open and close Outlook every time?) and using the existing `Outlook.Application` object if it's already open.

```vb
Sub Mail()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim oRng As Object
    
    Set wb = Workbooks("BankDetails.xlsm")
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("MessageBody")
    Set ws1 = wb.Sheets("Data")
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Batch")
    Set xlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MessageBody")
    xlSheet.TextBoxes("TextBox 1").Copy
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim i2 As Long 'For the number of passes (?)
    
    lastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If outApp Is Nothing Then
        Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        klient = ws2.Cells(i, "A")
        zalacznik1 = ws.Cells(4, "B") & ws.Cells(5, "B")
        zalacznik2 = ws.Cells(4, "B") & ws.Cells(6, "B")
        zalacznik3 = ws.Cells(4, "B") & ws.Cells(7, "B")
        
        'Create Item  Outlook Element
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        
        With OutMail
            'Sender e-mail address
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = ws.Cells(1, "B")
            
            'E-mail address of the recipient, can also be several with ; separate
            '.To = ws2.Cells(i, "B")
            
            .BodyFormat = 3
            .BCC = ws2.Cells(i, "B")
            
            'from column C
            .Subject = ws2.Cells(i, "C")
            
            .Display 'Needs to be displayed before opening Word Inspector
            Set wdDoc = .GetInspector.WordEditor
            'The text to send in column D
            'Maximum 1024 characters
            ws2.Cells(i, "D").Copy
            wdDoc.Paragraphs.first.Range.PasteSpecial 16 'wdFormatOriginalFormatting
            '.body = body
                                   
            'Add attachements w. reference to column B in sheets1 / MessageBody
            .Attachments.Add zalacznik1
            .Attachments.Add zalacznik2
            .Attachments.Add zalacznik3
            
'            Set oRng = wdDoc.TextBoxes
'            oRng.collapse 1
'            oRng.Paste
            
            'Here the e-mail is immediately placed in the outbox
            '.Send
        End With
        
        'Empty object variables
        Set OutMail = Nothing  'OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        Set olInsp = Nothing
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
        Set oRng = Nothing
        'Turn on pause
        'Outlook can't process the orders quickly enough, hence the pause
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        
       ' ws2.Cells(i, "D") = "Done"
        ws2.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Done, " & Now()
    Next i
End Sub
```